# Newtonsoft.JSON ignore [Required] attribute

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a field that is a foreign key for the many side of a one-to-many relationship (e.g. `Order` -> `LineItem`).  I want Entity Framework to mark the field non-null and add up the "on delete, cascade" relationship and so I decorate it with the `[Required]` attribute.  However, I don't want Newtonsoft.JSON to serialize or deserialize the field so I decorate it with the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute.  However, it appears the `[Required]` attribute trumps `[JsonIgnore]` as I am get an error stating the field is required.  Is there any way I can make this work?

```
public class LineItem
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Required]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: show the code where your getting the exception please

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?  To my knowledge, Json.Net does not look for the `[Required]` attribute at all.  It has its own mechanism for making fields required, e.g. `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]`.

Comment: I doubt that JSON.NET has anything to do with the error you're getting. Chances are, the object is being deserialized correctly, but the framework you're using (Web API? MVC?) is then blocking the request because it thinks the parameter it's taking is invalid. If you need the `OrderId` to *not* be required for a given request, then don't use the `LineItem` class. You can create a separate model where `OrderId` isn't required, or isn't present at all, based on your specific needs.

Comment: You are all correct, the issue was ASP.NET MVC's model state validation.  Typically when I get errors from this it was because of JSON errors but it turns out it does more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to put this as an answer, but the following code works:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LineItem item = new LineItem
            {
                OrderId = 10
            };


            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Formatting.Indented);
            var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LineItem>(json);
        }
        public class LineItem
        {
            [JsonIgnore]
            [Required]
            public int OrderId { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```